# Does choosing initial starting point for simplex construction influences the result of Nelder-Mead algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I was wondering how the choice of the initial vertex x0, and the step that is used to compute the others vertices, influence the final result given by the Nelder-Mead algorithm.
Is this susceptible to produce a local optimum around the x0?

Comment: Yes. Imagine f(x,y)=exp(-y*)*sin(x)+exp(-x)*sin(y) - a double sine surface with an exponential decay, still having their minima isolated from one to another, If your initial simplex is all into the collection basin of a local minimum with the vertices at half distance to nearby maxes, your simplex will never leave the local minimum.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi thanks for reply. My cost function is a Black Box function depending on 6 variables. I have no idea about its shape. In this case, choosing the X0 randomly is the single option?

Comment: How expensive is the function evaluation and do you know a rough range in which the optimum lies? If you can afford to evaluate the function in N  random points, your chance to narrow a good area to start your simplex goes increases roughly with sqrt(N). So, 10^4 random points would offer you roughly under 10% error in locating the minimum, Supplementary, considering the set of all random points, you can initialize your simplex to span over enough space to decrease the chances of collapsing too soon in a local minimum.

Comment: The function evaluation is quite expensive: it takes 10 minutes for 1 evaluation (it actually runs a simulation tool for pollutant propagation in river's water).

Comment: @Sorin: perhaps you could decrease the resolution of your data or the accuracy of the simulation for a few rounds?

Comment: You _can_ escape local minima by starting with a big enough initial simplex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the choice of starting point x0 influences the outcome of minimization (and this is not unique to Nelder-Mead method). Getting stuck in a local minimum is a very real possibility.

It's important to recognize that the method operates with a simplex (n+1 points in case of n variables). If the simplex is small compared to the size of landscape features, the trajectory will be gradient-like, approaching a nearest local minimum. If it's large, there will be a more global investigation of the function's landscape.

For example, SciPy implementation of this algorithm chooses the initial simplex [as follows](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f80aef74992d87e82a64378f0972e2d2f69ca674/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L473): the k-th vertex is x0 with its k-th coordinate increased by 5% (unless the coordinate is 0, in which case it's arbitrarily set to 0.00025). If you have a better idea of what region of parameters should be explored, try choosing `initial_simplex` yourself, so that its size is comparable to the size of the range being searched.

Comment: I normalized all my 6 variables to [0,1] range. I can use the steps in computing the initial simplex. Flanagan's java API uses a vector of steps to compute the rest of the n vertexes http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Minimisation.html. Basically, if I use some big values for steps I can cover a large area. Is this correct?

Comment: "Cover" in the sense "not bias the search toward local minima in the vicinity of x0", yes. Not in the sense of "will surely get the global minimum over the region covered by simplex"; nothing will give a guarantee of that. The animations at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method), especially the second one, give a good idea of what happens as the method runs: the simplex shrinks toward where the algorithm thinks the minimum will be. It may still turn out to be a local one.

Comment: Also, if each evaluation takes 10 minutes and you have 6 variables... any method will take forever. I think Richard's suggestion is a good one: use a cruder model for the large-scale search of the parameter space; then refine when you have a better idea of where to look.